# laravel different key hasMany relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

What I want my data from a hasMany relationship returned as an object instead of as an array.
What I have is:
Survey->Question->Answer->Info
This relationships work fine but I get info returned like this:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "some_info",
    "value": "this is just some info",
    "survey_answer_id": answer_id
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "more_info",
    "value": "this is some more info",
    "survey_answer_id": answer_id
}]
```

I want it to return as an object like this:

```
{
    "some_info": "this is just some info",
    "more_info": "this is some more info"
}
```

I did some research but found nothing that could help me.
I defined info as following in my Answers class:

```
public function info()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\SurveyAnswerInfo')->orderBy('priority');
}
```

and this is how I load it

```
$survey = Survey::find($id);
$survey->load('questions', 'questions.answers', 'questions.answers.info');
```

Answer (score 0):

in your answer model :

```
// this will append some_info and more_info in your answer object

public $appends=['some_info','more_info'];


public function info()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\SurveyAnswerInfo')->orderBy('priority')
}

public function getSomeInfoAttribute(){
return $this->info->pluck('value')->toArray();
}

public function getMoreInfoAttribute(){
return $this->info->pluck('value')->toArray();
}
```

in your controller you can access :

```
$some_info=Survey->Question->Answer->some_info;
$more_info=Survey->Question->Answer->more_info;
```

Comment: I think this is a wrong way. Relation method must return relation, not array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add accessor method to your Answer model:

```
public function getPreparedInfoAttribute(){
    return (object)$this-info->pluck('value', 'name')->toArray();
}
```

And access it:

```
$survey->question->answer->prepared_info->some_info;
$survey->question->answer->prepared_info->more_info;
```

You should add some checkings for nulls.